# Can timesheet app be built in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I've been tasked with developing a timesheet application in sharepoint.  Currently we use spreadsheets with a standard list of categories and then we add various subcategories/projects/tasks we are working on and our hours.

I've mostly built asp.net apps.  My question is do you think this type of application can be built using sharepoint using the standard lists and items in sharepoint without writing code?

I get the feeling that is won't work very well using sharepoint.

Comment: You can simplify your life by using some existing TFS Timetracking solution (like TX Chrono http://www.teamexpand.com/product/tx-chrono)) and just put link to it on you sharepoint portal. This will provide you with quick, cheap and high-quality reliable solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the ['Fab 40' Application Templates for Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb407286.aspx) that Microsoft released there is a [Timecard template](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=823A28A4-3FA3-4B55-B8AB-96FF5155752F&displaylang=en).

> The Timecard Management application
>   template for Microsoft Windows
>   SharePoint Services 3.0 helps teams
>   track hours spent working on various
>   projects.

Or how about [Create a Timesheet Application with SharePoint and Exchange](http://www.simego.com/Blog/2009/05/create-a-timesheet-application-with-sharepoint-and-exchange)

You could also look at adapting this [OSS TFS - Timesheet](http://tfstimesheet.codeplex.com/) project (Team Foundation Server is built upon SharePoint).

There are also quite a few commercial packages such as [PointBeyond's Straight Forward Timeshets](http://www.pointbeyond.com/products/Timesheets/Default.aspx). (no connection)

EDIT - New project on Codeplex that looks interesting - uses SQL DB for data store and UI in SharePoint - common compromise between surfacing UI via SP but keeping power of 'traditional' database.

[Codeplex - Timesheet for SharePoint 2010](http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2011/04/timesheet-for-sharepoint-2010-codeplex.html)

FURTHER EDIT - My company has written up a series of blog posts detailing all the options, templates, open source and commercial (*including our own - obvious disclaimer -  [TeamTime](http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/teamtime) product*).

**SharePoint Timesheets - What are your options?**

- [1 - Native commercial solutions](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/10/sharepoint-timesheets-what-are-your-options-part-1-native-commercial-solutions/)
- [2 - Plug in commercial solutions](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/11/sharepoint-timesheets-plug-in-commercial-solutions/)
- [3 - Free Solutions](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/11/sharepoint-timesheets-free-solutions/)

Answer (score 2):

Joining the halfway shameless-plug crowd on this one, you can have a look at what we have built as a 100% native SharePoint application. It leverages SharePoint lists and integration features, and integrates with Exchange, to allow your timesheets to be built (as SharePoint data) based on your calendar information.

We are planning a technical screencast sometime soon that might be of interest to you. Check out the demos section at http://www.puzzlepart.com/apps/Pages/did.aspx.